# Finding the area of an ellipse

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Using Green's Theorem, find the area of the ellipse $\frac{x^2}9+\frac{y^2}{16}=1$.

My work so far:

Green's Theorem states that $\iint_R \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} \, dA=\int_C P \, dx + Q \, dy$, where $R$ is the interior region and $C$ is the boundary of the region. To find area, I deduce that $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=1$.

Now, the area of the ellipse is $\pi (3)(4)=12$. How can I use Green's Theorem to verify this? I have $\mathbf{r}(t)=\langle 3 \cos t,4\sin t\rangle$.

Comment: I suppose you could choose your own $Q$ and $P$ for this problem, right? As long as $Q_x-P_y=1$.

Comment: it is $A=\pi ab$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simplest procedure here is to take
$$
Q = \frac{x}2 \\
P = -\frac{y}2
$$
then
$$
A = \frac12 \int_{t=0}^{t=2\pi} (-y)dx + xdy \\
= \frac12 \int_{0}^{2\pi}(-4\sin t)(-3\sin t dt) + (3\cos t)(4\cos t dt) \\
= \frac12 \int_{0}^{2\pi} 12(\sin^2 t +\cos^2 t) dt
=  12 \pi
$$

Comment: Why is it a good idea to have the vector field $\langle -\frac{y}2,\frac x2 \rangle$? That is, why do we have the $\frac 12$ factor for the ellipse? I do understand, however, that the vector field for a circle is $\langle -y,x \rangle$.

Comment: the $\frac12$ is required to give $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=1$ for the application of Green's theorem to calculate area via a contour integral

Answer (score 0):

For example, use $Q(x,y) = P(x,y) = x$ (why?). Now integrate the field $(P,Q)$ over the parametrization $\mathbf r$ (the one you give) of the border of the ellipse.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Use the form of Green's theorem that says 
$$
\oint_C \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{s} =  \int\int (\nabla\times \mathbf{F})\cdot d\mathbf{A}$$
Choose a function 
$$
\mathbf{F}(x,y) = ay \mathbf{\hat{x}} + bx \mathbf{\hat{y}}
$$
carefully choosing $a$ and $b$ such that

- $\nabla\times \mathbf{F} = 1$ everywhere so that the right hand side will be equal to the area. (This says $b^2-a^2 = 1$).
- At every spot on the ellipse, $\mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{s}$ is some constant $k$times $dr$.

Then since the integral around the boundary involves $r$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ the area will be $2\pi k$.